# Requests get method giving 401 with auth

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-requests

I am trying to get a response from an internal url which I can access through my laptop using a web-browser.

```
s = requests.Session()
r = s.get(url_1, auth=auth, verify=False)
print r.text
```

the reply i get is: 401 - unauthorized.

Answer (score 0):

It's obviously going to be difficult to debug an HTTP `401 Unauthorized` as we don't have access to the internal URL. Your code looks correct to me so I'm assuming this is a real `401 Unauthorized` which means the request has incorrect authentication credentials. My advice would be to make sure you have reviewed the Python [Requests docs on authentication](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/authentication/) and consider that your request is likely going through a proxy so the [Requests docs on proxy config](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#proxies) might be helpful.